# How do I copy my sqlite file from documents directory to app bundle using XCode menu and not programmatically

Tags: bundle

First Step: I want to add a pre populated  core data database file to app bundle i.e. . I ran my data loader app and can see the file under directory below

/Users//Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator//Applications//Documents

Next Step: I now want to add the *.sqlite file created above to my app bundle via XCode menu as in 'Add files to project' menu item.

I am getting stuck in the above step, unable to see the documents folder in the XCode when select 'Add Files to '.

The logic in my main app is I need to check if file exists in documents folder and if not copy from the app bundle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.Drag and drop .sqlite file from finder on to Xcode files section.

2.Run the code below from `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
BOOL successBool;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourDatabaseName.sqlite"];
successBool = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if (successBool) {
    return;
}
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourDatabseName.sqlite"];
successBool = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
if (!successBool) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy sqlite from app bundle '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```